# Pass shell variables to AWK for a IF statement

Tags: shell, variables, if-statement, awk

This is what I'm trying to break my head over... but it still doesn't work

This is what works:

```
awk '{
    if ( $2 ~ /FULL/ )
     print "TRUE" $0
   }' FILE1
```

But now I want to have the "/FULL/" part dynamic, so I can change this by linking it to a shell variable.

So this it what I want:

```
shellfull="/FULL/"

awk -v awkfull=$shellfull '{
    if ( $2 ~ awkfull )
    print "TRUE" $0
                            }' FILE1
```

Where FILE1 has the content:

```
84738273 RTF-Ref-FULL-Monday 
38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
84839489 FULL 
83945940 Schedule_FULL 
84928049 Schedule_DIFF
```

It kinda looks like it doesn't let me use awkfull inside the "IF" statment, because I can print awkfull and it shows me indeed the shell variable content.
What I mean:

```
print awkfull       //this works)
if ( $1 ~ awkfull)  //this does NOT work... why?
```

**UPDATE 1**

Ty all for the responses, some gave really good idea's. But I feel like I need to describe my exact situation. Because I really need the "/" in order to find a word on a reandom place in a string, and I don't know what the string is going to look like in advance.

So here is what I want to use it for:

```
//Set Variable Content:
FULL="/FULL/||/Full/||/full/||/SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month/"
DIFF="/DIFF/||/Diff/||/diff/||/San-Element/"
```

Now I have a big logfile, that has in one of its strings somewords that I'm going to use to determine if it counts as a FULL, or a DIFF, or maybe both based on if there is a word in $FULL or $DIFF matching a reandom place in that string

So if the stings in the file look like this:

```
84738273 RTF-Ref-full-Monday 
38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
84839489 FULL 
83945940 Schedule_Full_backup 
84928049 Schedule_DIFF
83940392 2_SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month-23049
84828348 Schedule_new-build
```

I want it to become:

```
FULL 84738273 RTF-Ref-full-Monday 
DIFFFULL 38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
FULL 84839489 FULL 
FULL 83945940 Schedule_Full 
DIFF 84928049 Schedule_DIFF
FULL 83940392 2_SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month-23049
UNKNOWN 84828348 Schedule_new-build
```

Now it is important to have the list with words that it is going to searche for setup in a dynamic way. So that with changing the variable $DIFF or $FULL it is going to search for different words in the file.

So how I wanted to achieve this was by the sript concept:

```
//set filter patterns
FULL="/FULL/||/Full/||/full/||/SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month/"
DIFF="/DIFF/||/Diff/||/diff/||/San-Element/" 

awk -v full=$FULL -v diff=$DIFF '{          //link the shell variable to awk variable, since a direct shell variable in awk didn't work.
if ( $2 ~ diff )                            //find all strings with words defined in $DIFF
print "DIFF" $0                             //print "DIFF" in front of the line
if ( $2 ~ full )                            //find all strings with words defined in $FULL
print "FULL" $0                             //print "FULL" in front of the line
if ( $2 !~ full||diff)                      //if a line does neighter contain words of $DIFF or $FULL.
print "UNKNOWN" $0                          //print "UNKNOWN" in front of the line
                        }' FILE1            //load the file that needs to be filterd
```

This script needs to make clear to me, and itself, if it finds Schedules and Policies that are not yet defined. This so that the scipt knows when a new unknown schedule or policy is created and can warn me that I needs to adjust its filter. And it gives the script the ability to calculate how much the calculated Kbytes are going to a "unknown schedules and policies pool"

Hope this makes things a bit more clear. I need to search for multiple reandom word *[FULL,full,SQL-DB,ect.]* in a reandom place inside a string *[thats why I wanted to use /$full/||/$diff/, or something like this*].

Comment: The answer has already been posted, but let me just add this as a comment: /regex/ is a regular expression constant; "string" is a string; and <lhs> ~ <rhs> takes rhs as a regular expression, converting a string to a regex if needed.  So in /regex/ the slashes are syntax bits that go away; having them in the string is like searching for /\/regex\// with a literal regex.

Comment: And so the expected output is...?

Comment: Now you know courtesy of @fedorqui how to pass the value of a shell variable to awk (use `-v awkvar="$shellvar"`). If you clarify what you're trying to do with some representative input and expected output we can show you what constructs to use in awk to get the output you want without false matches.

Comment: You're confused about the meaning if "/". It just delimits a constant regular expression, just like " delimits a constant string. `/foo/` is a regular expression while `"foo"` is a string. If you want to search for the words `foo` or `bar` as regular expressions, you write that as a single RE, i.e. `/foo|bar/`, and test it as `$0 ~ /foo|bar/`. If you want to populate a variable with a string and use that in an RE search context (using `~`) then you write that as `var="foo|bar"` and test it using `$0 ~ var` (there are caveats). Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it... I figured out already that it worked without the "/".. I have now written everything manually and it works now.. I'm not sure if I ever gonna get it dynamic.. so I will work with manual adjusting it for now.
Ty for the help

Comment: Did you look at the answer I posted? I think it does exactly what you eventually asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Your string does not need to have the `/` for the comparison. With the following it works:

```
shellfull="FULL"
```

#### Test

```
$ shellfull="EMPTY"
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull '$1 ~ patt {print "TRUE" $0}' a
TRUEEMPTY 3928304

$ shellfull="FULL"
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull '$1 ~ patt {print "TRUE" $0}' a
TRUEFULL 2930429
TRUEFULL 3940229
```

---

### Update

Based on the input file you just posted:

```
$ shellfull="FULL"
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull '$2 ~ patt {print "TRUE " $0}' a
TRUE 84738273 RTF-Ref-FULL-Monday 
TRUE 38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
TRUE 84839489 FULL 
TRUE 83945940 Schedule_FULL
```

In case you want exact matches:

```
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull '$2==patt {print "TRUE " $0}' a
TRUE 84839489 FULL
```

---

### Update 2

If you want to match different words that you pass through an string, let's do it like this:

```
awk -v patt=$shellfull 'BEGIN{split(patt,a,"|")} 
  {for (i in a) if ($2==a[i]) {print "TRUE " $0; next}}' a
```

It gets the string, explodes it by the delimiter `|` (you can define another) and then looks for exact matches of each one of the given strings.

#### Test

```
$ shellfull="Schedule_DIFF|FULL"
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull 'BEGIN{split(patt,a,"|")} {for (i in a) if ($2==a[i]) {print "TRUE " $0; next}}' a
TRUE 84839489 FULL 
TRUE 84928049 Schedule_DIFF 

$ shellfull="FULL"
$ awk -v patt=$shellfull 'BEGIN{split(patt,a,"|")} {for (i in a) if ($2==a[i]) {print "TRUE " $0; next}}' a
TRUE 84839489 FULL
```

Comment: I need to have / because in the real file the file will have content like:

     84738273 RTF-Ref-FULL-Monday
     38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL
     84839489 FULL
     83945940 Scheduled_FULL

Comment: @AcEKrystal please update your post showing the file content. In comments we are losing the format, so it is not clear how it looks like.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want false positive so use boundary matching, anchoring or better yet string comparisons if the field is fixed.

Comment: @AcEKrystal you should be able to put into the shell variable a regex that meets your needs. I believe `awk` will take it as a regex even though it doesn't have the `/` delimiters.

Comment: The fields are not fixed.. thats my problem.. and then also comes.. that the total I want to compare it against is "/FULL/||/Full/||SQL-backup-dump/"

Comment: @AcEKrystal just updated, see `Update 2` in which I show how to exactly match different words.

Comment: @sudo_O it became a little bit trick, I finally did a `split()` on the string he passes, so that I can do a string comparison on each one of them.

Comment: @fedorqui Hi, Thanks for ya time already... I gave my post 1 more update to hope to clear things up what I precisely want to achieve. I hope ya can look at it one more time for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with:

```
shellfull="/FULL/"

awk '{
     if ( $1 ~ '$shellfull' )
     print "TRUE" $0
}' FILE1
```

This looks like it's now quoting the `$shellfull` variable, but it's actually "unquoting" it so that the shell will look at it.

Comment: This is very bad, do not do this!

Comment: Why is it bad to do this?

Comment: What if the script is in a file? What is `shellfull` contains special characters such as `*`? The structure of `awk` is `condition{block}` so `{if ($1~p)stuff}` should just `$1~p{stuff}` and you are comparing against the wrong field. Don't hack quoting, it makes things impossible to read and can have very bad consensuses.

Comment: @sudo_O is 100% correct, never do this. Try setting a shell variable like this `x="#b#"` and then using awk to see if that string exists in some input the right way (`echo "a#b#c" | awk -v re="$x" '$0 ~ re'`) and the wrong way as shown above (`echo "a#b#c" | awk '$0 ~ '$x''`). Enjoy the cryptic syntax error from the latter - many worse and much more cryptic results can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest update, it sounds like all you need is:

```
$ FULL="FULL|Full|full|SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month"
$ DIFF="DIFF|Diff|diff|San-Element"

$ cat file
84738273 RTF-Ref-full-Monday 
38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
84839489 FULL 
83945940 Schedule_Full_backup 
84928049 Schedule_DIFF
83940392 2_SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month-23049
84828348 Schedule_new-build

$ awk -v full="$FULL" -v diff="$DIFF" '{
    if ( ( $2 ~ diff ) && ( $2 ~ full ) )
        print "DIFFFULL", $0
    else if ( $2 ~ diff )
        print "DIFF", $0
    else if ( $2 ~ full )
        print "FULL", $0
    else
        print "UNKNOWN", $0
}' file
FULL 84738273 RTF-Ref-full-Monday 
DIFFFULL 38473847 The-Wed-DLL-DIFF-Fri-FULL 
FULL 84839489 FULL 
FULL 83945940 Schedule_Full_backup 
DIFF 84928049 Schedule_DIFF
FULL 83940392 2_SQL-Backup_Fri-Last-Of-Month-23049
UNKNOWN 84828348 Schedule_new-build
```

but you need to decide if it's OK for words like "Different" to match with "Diff" if they happen to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Error while running below command:

`Spacedata_1` is a file
`mountpoint` is external variable with some value

```
grep "$mountpoint" Spacedata_1 |awk -v mountpoint=$mountpoint 'if ($5==mountpoint ) { print $4 }'
```